# What should I use for SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok, so here is my dilemma. I j ust started working with `SQLite database's` in android and I came across the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) on the Android Developer website. Now I thought that this was pretty cool and was messing around with it until I noticed that Android Studio said that some of the code was `deprecated`.

One of the deprecated code was `startManagingCursor`. I decided to look into it more and found something called a `CursorLoader` with a `ContentProvider`, so I decided to look them up and it seems like the `CursorLoader` with a `ContentProvider` is a better choice. The problem is that I can't find a decent example that doesn't go into outrageous complexity. Like I said I just started learning this and I would like not to sit and try to figure out what someone else's code does for 3 hours.

So are there any good `tutorials` or `examples` that don't over complicate this topic so that I have a chance to learn it?

Comment: No, if you want a database, you will need SQLiteDatabase anyway. Don't do ContentProvider and Loader at this stage, do the database, follow the Notepad tutorial, first thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Example Code

```
package com.prgguru.example;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
 
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class SQLiteCrudExample  extends ListActivity {
    //DB name
    private final String dbName = "Android";
    //Table name
    private final String tableName = "Versions";
    //String array has list Android versions which will be populated in the list
    private final String[] versionNames= new String[]{"Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean", "Kitkat"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Declare SQLiteDatabase object
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;
         
        try {
            //Instantiate sampleDB object
            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            //Create table using execSQL
            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName +    " (versionname VARCHAR);");
            //Insert Android versions into table created
            for(String ver: versionNames){
                sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " Values ('"+ver+"');");
            }
             
            //Create Cursor object to read versions from the table
            Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT versionname FROM " + tableName, null);
            //If Cursor is valid
            if (c != null ) {
                //Move cursor to first row
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //Get version from Cursor
                        String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("versionname"));
                        //Add the version to Arraylist 'results'
                        results.add(firstName);
                    }while (c.moveToNext()); //Move to next row
                } 
            }
             
            //Set the ararylist to Android UI List
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
             
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't create or open the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            if (sampleDB != null) {
                sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
                sampleDB.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

===

There is an example source code [here](http://download.androidhive.info/download?code=KufjhcMdoRmd3xiZcpbacsVZwpXhITG7hSyZnHR8TaCX%2FUiyWnN9tEGm9B%2BMtrfHvEYZIkmz1bmIvT5Mu9XemL8sO0IE61XFNJy1Sx2KuuxGIB1qD8Pydswjw%3D%3DuCPL5H9KT9xXxcXi5CUoG3uYhEElTJxyp6b) to download

Also try this links:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: Link only answer, bad formatted, no explanations. This kind of "answer" is not welcome here. Please invest more time and explain...

Comment: I like the vogella links

Comment: Thanks for the links and the example. I think I'm starting to get the hang of it.